# ffmpeg restreaming to nginx, connection refused

Tags: ffmpeg, nginx, rtmp

New to ffmpeg and read a dozen of guides and howto, but still can't get it to work.

I have a Tvheadend server that receives channels from DVB, the channels work without any problem, but I need to transcode it so that U can see the channel outside my home.

I tried installing nginx+rtmp module with ffmpeg on a more powerful server (ubuntu 18.08), but whatever I do I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
ffmpeg -f mpegts -i http://username:password@192.168.0.14:4445/stream/channelid/9 -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -vb 1000k -acodec libfacc -ar 48000 -ab 48k -f flv rtmp://192.168.0.58:1935/test
```

The source is a tvheadend server and the rtmp server is the ffmpeg where the transcoding is going to be done.

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.2-2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x557f8caccca0] no frame!
[mp3 @ 0x557f8cacdee0] Header missing
Input #0, mpegts, from 'http://username:password@192.168.0.14:4445/stream/channelid/14':
  Duration: N/A, start: 71505.814511, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ?
      service_provider: ?
    Stream #0:0[0x50f]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first), 704x576 [SAR 16:11 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0xd10](dan): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
Unknown encoder 'libfacc'
```

Update:
Just change the audio codec to aac, but now i get this

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.2-2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[mp3 @ 0x5572191f6de0] Header missing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x5572191f5ba0] Increasing reorder buffer to 2
Input #0, mpegts, from 'http://username:password@192.168.0.14:4445/stream/channelid/9':
  Duration: N/A, start: 79841.014511, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ?
      service_provider: ?
    Stream #0:0[0x50f]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first), 704x576 [SAR 16:11 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0xd10](dan): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
[tcp @ 0x5572194ef060] Connection to tcp://192.168.0.58:1935 failed: Connection refused
[rtmp @ 0x5572194b65e0] Cannot open connection tcp://192.168.0.58:1935
rtmp://192.168.0.58:1935/test: Connection refused
```

Comment: Hi slhck, sorry, just updated the question with more infor

Comment: "Unknown encoder 'libfacc'" — start with that issue. Use `-acodec aac` instead.

Comment: Next time when editing your question, please make sure to use proper grammar and formatting. Use the code button (`{}`) to format console output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the aac syntax did work, but now i get a connection refused error

Comment: Well, do you have a server running on 192.168.0.58 and listening on TCP port 1935? If not, you have to configure and start the server appropriately.

Comment: i tried installing nginx-rtmp on the same server. nginx is running, the default nginx is showing. but dont sure if the nginx.conf is curret.

Comment: You haven't shown your `nginx.conf` so it's hard to tell. Look into your nginx logs — and `netstat -altun` can show you open ports. Note that this is not a live-troubleshooting site. It'd be better if you could show more info about what you've tried and what the problem is.

Comment: How did you solve the problem? Other readers would benefit from the solution. You could post it as an answer to your own question below.

Comment: I re-installed the nginx- rtmp module and made sure that the rtmp port was open using `netstat - altun` and made sure that the string of ffmpeg was the same as the nignx server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP solved the problem by re-installing the `nginx-rtmp` module, making sure that the RTMP port was open using `netstat -altun`. He also made sure that the string of ffmpeg was the same as the nignx server.